# Need some solution for resolving a 404 error of WordPress AMP

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, amp-html

I'm a beginner of AMP from Japan.

Now I'm in trouble dealing with a error that is output when I introduce AMP into my WordPress webpage.

I cloud activate [the AMP plugin](https://ja.wordpress.org/plugins/amp/) and display [an AMP of the post page](https://alan-d-haller.info/camera/ilko_talkshow/amp/) without problem.
But the following error was output on my browser console when I added *#development=1* to the end of URL of the post AMP to confirm whether the post AMP was configured as a valid AMP on Google.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/validator_minified.js.sourcemap
```

Then I accessed to the above URL described in the error message, the following error page was displayed.

```
Google
404. That’s an error.
The requested URL /v0/validator_minified.js.sourcemap was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

I guess the output post AMP may not be recognized by Google as a structure of AMP if this error page was displayed.
But I have no idea to resolve the 404 error and can't progress any more.

In other words, **I'd like to know some solution and hints to resolve the 404 error in order that Google recognizes my post AMP.**

If you have some solution or hints, I'd be very helpful if you provide them for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

clear your cache in the server and delete your log. Blocking an malicious IP trafics and your see the IP in 30 per connection then you want blocked the IP.

Using proxy or like mitigation

Comment: I appreciate your advice.I'll try it. Thank you very much.